# Can the variables in my php website over written, if there are two users from different locations?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

I am making a quiz in PHP. I have many questions in my database, User will select the category, and the questions from that category will be displayed.

I have two questions regarding this:

1. **Can I display questions one by one in php without using java script?**
2. **When there are two users on my site, and they select two different categories, will the variable I am posting to the database be overwritten?**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Each user has its own session, so the answers of several users will not interfere which each other. However, you need to make sure to save the answers in a proper way to later distinguish the answer sets (e.g. by saving a session id along with the answer).

Comment: They are different requests. You read about requests and reponses first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sessions ([Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php)). at the very top of your php file type:

```
session_start();
```

and then you can use it as global variables unique to every user. For example:

```
$_SESSION['last_question_id'] = 3;
$_SESSION['score_so_far'] += 1; // increases score by one
```

etc.

Also, please be more specific with your problem, maybe post some code or specific situations.

Answer (score 1):

PHP variables cannot be overridden by another user. They are unique for each user session, because each runs in its own copy of the script for that request.

Data in your Database *can* be overwritten by other users. If two users edit the same question at the same time, there´s no real way to predict which version will end up in the database. This is something your program will have to manage for itself.

Answer (score 0):

No, the database will not be overwritten. For displaying questions one by one, you can use the following:

```
$content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
```

If you want to display all the pages one by one, you can try using the function `get_pages()`.

But then again, it depends on what "type" of PHP you are using.